# Ctype function for both alphabetic and nummeric inputs

Tags: php, ctype

Is there  way for checking if an input contains both alphabetic and numeric characters with Ctype?

Comment: Did you try `ctype_alnum ` function?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`ctype_alnum`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

```
<?php
$strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#$bar');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all letters or digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all letters or digits.\n";
    }
}
?>
```